# How can I display a view title with 'No Results Behaviour'?

Tags: views

Using Drupal V 7.34 and Views 7.x.38

On the front page I have a view that lists news articles based on publish date being in the last 2 weeks. This works fine.

What I am now wanting is to insert a new view to pull images from Flickr when there are no news articles to show.

So, I created a new view for the Flickr feed, and adjusted the paging as I wanted. I set up the No Results Behaviour to show my new view in the Global View Area.

This works, but the title of the view is not displayed.

How can I show the title of the NRB view?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

i believe this is your problem

https://www.drupal.org/node/1602058

solution is here

https://www.drupal.org/node/1176080

If you have a view and you want to be able to programmatically change the title of, you can do it by implementing hook_views_pre_render in your custom module:
alter it when particular view or field is not having any result

```
<?php
function mymodule_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  if ($view->name == 'my_view_name' && $view->current_display == 'my_display_id') {
    // Here you can do any php you want to get the title you need for your view.
    $view->build_info['title'] = "My custom title!";
  }
}
?>
```

If you are altering the query and you have argument substitutions affecting the title, you can change these in hook_views_query_alter:

```
<?php
function mymodule_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if ($view->name == 'my_view_name' && $view->current_display == 'my_display_id') {
      // First substitution - you may want !1 or %2, etc
      $view->build_info['substitutions']['%1'] = $new_substitution;
    }
}
?>
```

Views Displayed as Pages

Use this:

```
drupal_set_title('My custom title!');
```

Instead of:

```
$view->build_info['title'] = "My custom title!";
```

or some thing like this in views 3

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_views_pre_view().
 */
function MODULENAME_views_pre_render($view) {
  if ($view->name == 'my_view_name') {
    if ($view->current_display == 'my_display_name') {
      $view->set_title('my new title');
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: OK, thanks Deveraj.... Although this now extends past my knowledge of the php for Drupal, still....  I assume I can create a php function somewhere that will override the default Views one?

Comment: yes you can override the default one by your custom title by adding some condition based on your requirement

Comment: still you face issue in displaying the title for no result behavior. none of the above methods worked Darren

Answer (score 0):

[There is a patch to Views here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1388332) that will display the title from the View set in the No Results Behavior. Hopefully it will eventually be accepted into the module, but hasn't been reviewed for two years.